# FFMPEG - Audio missing after combining video

Tags: ffmpeg

I was trying to combine two separate video into one side by side using ffmpeg using the following command in ubuntu server.

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -loglevel quiet -ss 0 -t 220.162 -i left.webm 
-ss 0 -t 220.162 -i right.webm -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:-1,pad=2*iw:2*ih:0:120[left];
[1]scale=320:-1[right];[left][right]overlay=main_w/2:120,scale=640:480" -shortest output.mp4
```

The video is processed successfully as expected. But the audio is missing from right.webm. Audio from one video is missing from the output.mp4.
How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mix both audios, else ffmpeg will pick one from among the inputs.

`ffmpeg -y -threads 4 -loglevel quiet -ss 0 -t 220.162 -i left.webm 
-ss 0 -t 220.162 -i right.webm -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:-1,pad=2*iw:2*ih:0:120[left];
[1]scale=320:-1[right];[left][right]overlay=main_w/2:120,scale=640:480;[0][1]amix" -shortest output.mp4`